# Creating multiple observations from single observation depending on conditions

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have written a function in python with three loops which is time consuming. Is it possible to do the same operation in less time with some other way.
Here are my code and sample data you can run at your end

```
#Expand files to minute-level
def expand_b34(data):
    final_list = []
    df_columns = list(data.columns.tolist())
    for i in range(len(data)):
      #print i
      row_list = np.repeat(data.values[i][np.newaxis,:],     data['DURATION'].loc[i], axis=0).tolist()
      start_end_list = range(data['START'].loc[i], data['END_MINUTE'].loc[i])
      for j in range(len(row_list)):
        row_list[j].extend([start_end_list[j]])
      for k in row_list:
        final_list.append(k)

   data = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
   data.columns = df_columns + ['START_MINUTE']
   data = data.drop(['START','END_MINUTE'], axis=1)

   return data               

df = expand_b34(test)
```

> ```
> Sample data
> date  Id     LD GOOD_AP_ORIG ap_station JULIAN_DAY START DURATION END_MINUTE PLDS PL PLT PLAY
> 16080 4012007 1 G            5000       16081       0       60       60      0    0   0  
> 16080 4012007 1 G            5000       16081      60       60      120      0    0   0  
> 16080 4012007 1 G            5000       16081     120       60      180      0    0   0  
> 16080 4012007 1 G            5000       16080     180       60      240      0    0   0  
> 16080 4012007 1 G            5000       16080     240      120      360      0    0   0
> ```

[image: Attached is the sample data for your reference]

Code Work flow:

1. calculate difference between `START` and `END_MINUTE`
2. expand the observations for the difference

So if the difference is `10`, ten more lines of observations will be generated for the observation which is having the same data except for the `START_MINUTE` variable. `START_MINUTE` starts at `0` (because for that particular observation `START == 0`) and ends at `9`.

For a single observation the loop creates 10 duplicate observations except for the start minute variable, which varies from 0 to 9.

Can someone help me to do the same observation expansion by optimizing my code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review ,  I hope you get good answers.

Comment: Optimize for what? Speed or memory? Are either giving you issues?

Comment: @Bey The description of the tag [tag:performance] answers your first two questions: "Performance is a subset of Optimization: performance is the goal when you want the execution time of your program or routine to be optimal."

Comment: Have you tried using `pypy` instead of `CPython`, `pypy` excels at repeated calls because of the JIT (the only thing that might give it trouble is Pandas). See my answer here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144196/82612

~10x perfomance increase only switching from `CPython` to `pypy`.

Comment: How slow? I re-worked your script and got it down to 5 lines and one `for` loop with a couple of list comprehensions. While it may *look* more elegant than yours, your function is 5 times faster! However, your `START_MINUTE` is a running count of all records not just for each corresponding row of original df.